# Variable in preg_quote fails in preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex

Using a variable, $key, in preg_replace_callback fails, but what looks like the exact same text works just fine: `"%\[if @$username\](.*?)\[/if\]%"`

What is confusing is that I'm using preg_quote and the pattern is in double quotes.

$pattern produces `%\[if @username\](.*?)\[/if\]%` which fails (no error)
but writing in  `%\[if @username\](.*?)\[/if\]%`  works just fine

```
public function output() {
if (!file_exists($this->file)) {
    return "Error loading template file ($this->file).<br />";
}
$output = file_get_contents($this->file);

foreach ($this->values as $key => $value) {
    $tagToReplace = "[@$key]";
    $output = str_replace($tagToReplace, $value, $output);
    $regex_key = preg_quote($key);
    $pattern = "%\[if @$regex_key\](.*?)\[/if\]%"; // produces: %\[if @username\](.*?)\[/if\]%
    $output = preg_replace_callback($pattern, array($this, 'if_replace'), $output);
}

return $output;
}

public function if_replace($matches) {

    $matches[0] = preg_replace("%\[if @username\]%", "", $matches[0]);
    $matches[0] = preg_replace("%\[/if]%", "", $matches[0]);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

Comment: how do you know it fails? what is the error message?

Comment: `preg_quote` needs to be told your delimiter. Also, it _seems_ you are working with regexes where writing a parser would make more sense.

Comment: @Shiplu -- no error message, but nothing is replaced.

Comment: @Wrikken, thanks for the help. Got it -- but in this case variable is username so when i echo $pattern it matches the handwritten pattern exactly? Began this by working off of regex template engine tutorials, interested if you have any links showing parser example?

Comment: This seems to fix the problem: `$pattern = '%\[if @'.$regex_key.'\](.*?)\[/if\]%'; // produces: %\[if @username\](.*?)\[/if\]%`

Answer (score 0):

You propably have a variable-scope problem. If php inserts the variable-name itself instead of it's value then php does not know the variable. As you are using the $username variable in the callback method you might have to declare it global first and import it into the method by adding

```
global $username;
```

to if_replace()

Answer (score 0):

Changing the way the $pattern was constructed to the code below seems to resolve the issue:

OLD:

```
  $pattern = "%\[if @$regex_key\](.*?)\[/if\]%";
```

NEW:

```
 $pattern = '%\[if @'.$regex_key.'\](.*?)\[/if\]%';
```